# Gmail keeps blocking when I use ActionMailer

Tags: gmail, block, actionmailer, account

After a while my gmail account that I use to send e-mail with the ActionMailer (and delayed-jobs) gets blocked.

```
534-5.7.9 Please log in with your web browser and then try again. Learn more at 

/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:960:in `check_auth_response'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:737:in `auth_plain'
....
```

When I subsequently log in to my gmail account it asks for captcha like authorization, i.e. checking if I am a real human being.

The account is used to send below 100 e-mail messages a day.

Is there a way to surpass this blockage? Or is the only option to use a different bulk e-mail service?